# Java Generics WildCard - How can I use generic with Lambda here?

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8

I am trying to create a generic method. My dtos are:

```
public class Master {
    private String string;
    private Date date;

    public String getString() {
        return this.string;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return this.date;
    }

    public void setString(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

My Child class which extends Master is:

```
public class Child extends Master {

    private Date newDate;

    public Date getNewDate() {
        return this.newDate;
    }

    public void setNewDate(Date newDate) {
        this.newDate = newDate;
    }
}
```

Now, what I want to do is create a generic method to get -

```
public static <T extends Master> Map<String, Map<Date, List<T extends Master>>> getRecalculateMasterMappedByInstrumentIdAndDate(List<T extends Master> masters) {
        return masters.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Child::getString, Collectors.groupingBy(x -> org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils.truncate(x.getDate(), Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))));
    }
```

The above is giving me an error during compile time. How can I write a generic method for the same?

Comment: You cannot use `Child` inside the method as the compiler does not know about it. Compiler knows only `Master`. Either remove the bound or use `Master` only methods. Here abstract method in master will help you do that as well

Answer (score 1):

Remove the bound after the declaration:

- Return type: `Map<String, Map<Date, List<T>>>`
- Parameter type: `List<T> masters`.

You only use bounds with wildcards (`?`), or in the declaration of the type variables.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand the difference between the *declaration* of a type variable and the *use* of the type variable. When you write

```
public static <T extends Master> Map<String, Map<Date, List<T>>>
    getRecalculateMasterMappedByInstrumentIdAndDate(List<T> masters) {
    …
}
```

The `<T extends Master>` declares the type variable `T` including the constraint that `T` must be a subtype of `Master`. The other occurrences of `T` within the return type `Map<String, Map<Date, List<T>>>` and the parameter type `List<T>` are *using* the type variable `T` and don’t need to repeat (and are in fact not allowed to repeat) the bounds of `T`.

Note that you also have to use `Master::getString` in the method implementation as you can’t assume that `T` is a `Child`. It may be `Child`, but the caller can also use `Master` or any subclass of it for `T`. Thankfully, `getString` has been defined in `Master` anyway, so you don’t need to assume `Child` here.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve with the help of folks here. Thank you, guys. My solution:

```
public static <T extends Master> Map<String, Map<Date, List<T>>> getMastersMappedByInstrumentIdAndDateForRecalculation(List<T> masters) {
        return masters.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Master::getString, Collectors.groupingBy(x -> org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils.truncate(x.getDate(), Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))));
    }
```